# I cant run filesource<->uhd/any sink flowgraph on gnuradio and high samplate

Tags: gnuradio, transmission, usrp, sample-rate, uhd

I am going to transmit the complex data produced from **matlab** by using **usrp b210** and **gnuradio** on windows.
**gnuradio flowgraph** is following:

[image]

Here, data type is complex.
Problem:
I want sample-rate is **20MHz or 30.72MHz,** but **gnuradio is stoped**, logging out *'UUUUUUU...'* or *'UUOUUUUU...'*.

why?, and how to fix it? please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRC will even warn you that you must not use a throttle block in your flow graph if you have hardware. Read the console log!

Other than that, you're expecting your storage to read and write simultaneously 16 MS/s · (32 bit I + 32 bit Q) = 1.024 Gb/s, reliably. It's also not very likely it's fast enough to do that.

Comment: thank muller, i deleted throttle block, but the problem not solved.

Comment: so, i used only usrp sink or only source. "16 MS/s · (32 bit I + 32 bit Q) = 1.024 Gb/s", i think it is the GRC's performance problem. the logging 'U' or 'O' means buffer overflow, doesn't it?

Comment: GRC is not involved in executing this flow graph. This is almost certainly a storage bottleneck, as I explained.

Comment: i used only file sink / source and usrp sink/source, but not solved. i agree your idea, Marcus Müller. how can i solve it?

Comment: You'll need faster storage! That's not something I can help you solve...